# Multiple custom thumbs pager

Tags: javascript, jquery, bxslider

i'm try to create multiple custom pager thumbs for the same sliders with bxslider,  here my jsfiddle.

Currently i have one main sliders that must be managed with two thumbs side pager , both independently have to control the main one.
At the click of a side thumbnail i want change the image in the main slider.

```
<!-- The main images -->
<ul id="bxslider">
  <li><img src="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff.png" alt=""></li>
  <li><img src="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/ff0099.png" alt=""></li>
  <li><img src="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/ff0000.png" alt=""></li>
  <li><img src="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff000.png" alt=""></li>
  <li><img src="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff.png" alt=""></li>
  <li><img src="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff.png" alt=""></li>
</ul>
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DcpdT/188/)

Comment: What is your question? What is not working as you expect?

Comment: i have 2 pager for 1 slider, but on my jsfiddle don't work.

Comment: so i want use both pager for the same slider

Comment: Could you improve your question by adding notes from your comments directly to question? More people will answer.